# Neo4j 3.1.0 apoc.export.graphml issue

Tags: stored-procedures, neo4j

I am trying to export my db as a graphml file via the apoc.export.graphml procedure in Neo4j 3.1 + 3.1.0.3:

```
call apoc.export.graphml.all("test",{})
```

I get this error message:

> Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.export.graphml.all`: Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Import from files not enabled, please set
>   apoc.import.file.enabled=true in your neo4j.conf

I have edited my neo4j.conf file to add

> apoc.import.file.enabled=true

at the end of the document but I'm still getting the same error message.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you shut down and start back up your neo4j instance? I don't think config changes are reflected in the db until you restart it.

Comment: I did, I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I originally added

> apoc.import.file.enabled=true

to the end of the neo4j.conf file and "HTTP logging configuration" section.

I moved the comment to the "Server configuration" section and now it works.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and did not find any from anywhere.  I just managed to resolved this issue.  Hopefully, this solves yours as well.

Environment: MacOs, Neo4j 3.1.2 CE

1) Change your .neo4j.conf (mine is under my ~/Documents/Neo4j/).  You can easily edit by pressing [Options...] button.  I commented the import directory comment out as well, just in case.

```
#dbms.directories.import=import
apoc.import.file.enabled=true
```

2)  I originally have the apoc-3.1.2.5.jar under ~/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/plugins/ directory which worked except reading xml from the local disk.  So, I put the jar under my app directory, /Applications/Neo4j.app/Contents/Resources/app/plugins

The "Neo4j.app" is my symbolic link.  You probably will see the app directory as "Neo4j Community Edition 3.1.2.app"

3) Do Not restart by pressing [Stop] and [Start], make sure you quit the Neo4j and relaunch.  Stop and Start seems to reload config but it does not seem to load jar from plugins.

4) How to check:

```
call apoc.config.list
```

You should see:

```
apoc.import.file.enabled    true
```