# Can't import file on Neo4j with RuntimeException error

Tags: json, neo4j

I have updated the `neo4j.conf` file but can't seem to get rid of this error after changing the file and restarting. I am just trying to load a json file through neo4j and have included the line `apoc.import.file.enabled=true` on the `neo4j.conf` but doesn't seem to be working for me, I'm still getting the error message:

> Failed to invoke procedure 'apoc.load.json' Caused by
>   java.lang.RuntimeException : Import from files not enabled, please set
>   apoc.import.file.enabled=true in your neo4j.conf

I am using neo4jCE 3.2.3 and have used the right file path for the json file as it previously worked on my desktop computer (I'm just trying to replicate it on my laptop) and I am using apoc 3.2.0.4 version plugin. The procedure apoc.load.json is also there when I call all procedures directory.

Comment: Which SO are you using? What version?

Comment: Are you putting the CSV file into the right directory? How looks like your import script? Please, edit your question and add more details about your problem.

Comment: hey I've just updated the question with more info.. didn't have a long time to write the question at the time. I'm importing JSON file and put the version in the question now.

Comment: Are you editing the `neo4j.conf` file in the right location? Take a look in the [file locations doc](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/#file-locations).

Comment: Also take a look in [this (strange) solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41803258/6835358) :)

Comment: yeah I'm sure its the right location as it's in AppData and the only conf file I have for Neo4j.. I also tried that solution but its still telling me the same thing, thanks anyway:)